# the onChildAdded callback gets called but there nothing a add

Tags: android, firebase

i have a problem that the onChildAdded() gets called for no reason ,and it does work properly when some thing add

this is the listener :

```
    comment = new Firebase(MY_URL).child("Comments").child(channel);
    childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        try {
                        comment = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(commentObject);
                        System.out.println("onChildAdded"+comment +"    s"+s);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

        }
        //the other call backs
    };
    comment.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

this is the initializes Code where i add the listener :

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setupFireBaseListener(channel);
    }
```

this is ware i remove the listener :

```
 @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        comment.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
    }
```

note that i call this method on the Application class:

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
```

this is the data that i have printed :

```
onChildAdded{"name":"osama raddad","comment":"hi","user_id":"11"}    s-K7qX32GeNLEvY4IDtnn oldData
onChildAdded{"name":"osama raddad","comment":"how","user_id":"11"}    s-K7qX3UCI6vlcS5kfBdG oldData
```

my firebase client sdk version is 2.2.1

Comment: Do you know what happens when the listeren is called? Maybe data being changed or deleted? If you do can you add the code for that change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onChildAdded` does not just fire off for every added child after you are connected, but it also fires off **for each existing child**.

Below is from the Firebase docs.

> ...the `onChildAdded` [event is triggered once](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-types) for each existing child
>   and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path.

If you want only the newly added items, you'll need to include a timestamp with each item and then do an `orderByChild("timestamp").start(currentTimestamp)` query.